# Seleccionar id dinamicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo un formulario que voy llenando con datos de un producto.necesito saber como puedo trabajar con id dinámicos,buscando en Internet aprendí que se deben agregar corchetes al final del id de esta forma: `name="id[]"` pero mi problema es que no sé como llamarlos en el selector de jquery.
Al momento de seleccionar un botón del producto deseado se solicita la información de ese producto y lleno mis `td` e `input` correspondientes de la siguiente forma:

```
var cant = prompt("Ingresar Cantidad:");

if(cant>0){
$('#cod[]').val(data.ID); //probé con esto pero no me dio resultado
```

Los antes de enfrentarme al problema de agregar los datos a la tabla correspondiente los trabajaba de esta forma incrementando una variable en 1

```
var $cant = $('#qty'+idqty).text(cant);
idqty ++;
$('#producto'+idprod).text(data.DESC);
idprod ++;
$('#precio'+idpre).val(data.PRECIO);
idpre ++;
agrega_fila();
calcular_valores(cant,data.PRECIO);

}else{
    alert ("La cantidad debe ser mayor a 0");
}
```

El problema es que no tengo idea de como insertar los datos de la forma que me funciona (incrementado la variable con cada iteración)

Código del formulario:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="contenido">
                        <h3>Detalle</h3>
                        <form id="detalle-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal style-form" >
                            <input id="n-mesa" name="n-mesa" hidden="" type="number"></th>

                          <table class="table table-fixed" id="pedido">
                          <thead>
                             <tr>
                             <th class="col-xs-2">Codigo</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-2">Qty</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-2">Descripción</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-3">Peso</th>
                              <th class="col-xs-3">Precio</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                            <tr id="fila0">
                                <td class="col-xs-2">
                                         <div class="input-group"><input id="cod[]" class="form-control input-md"  type="text"></div>
                                 </td>
                                <td class="col-xs-2" id="qty0"></td>
                                 <td class="col-xs-2" id="producto0"></td>
                                 <td class="col-xs-3">
                                         <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">Kg</div><input id="peso0" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="col-xs-3">
                                         <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="precio0" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                             <tfoot>
                             </table>
                             <table class="table">
                             <tr >
                              <td  class="col-xs-3"></td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3"></td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">Total :</td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">
                                     <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="total" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td  class="col-xs-3"><button title="Guardar registro" id="save" name="save" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></button>
                                                    <button class="btn btn-success "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></button>
                              </td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3"></td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">Propina Sugerida 10% </td>
                                  <td class="col-xs-3">
                                     <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="propina" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                  </form>
```

Comment: como tienes tu formulario..puedes agregar tu codigo de el..!!

Comment: Agregue el código a la publicación

Comment: Como recomendación, te sugiero que antes de enviar tu pregunta, la leas y veas si esta bien redactada, si se entiende lo que querías poner, y que si agrega código, que sea en un formato legible. De este modo es más fácil recibir una buena respuesta.

Comment: te sugiero obtener valores en base a la clase

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vxLgn03m/